# Java.lang.String.contains() Method with "" String

Tags: java

I have writen a code like this:

```
    String name="";
    String path="hai";
    if(path.contains(name))
    {
        System.out.println("its working"+name.length());
    }
```

Output:
its working0

I couldn't understand how  the if condition satisfies .please help

Comment: It's not much of a question. An empty string is a substring of the string (here). I guess you're asking why, but the answer to that is: because that's how `contains` works. (And from a set perspective it makes sense, with the empty string being the empty set).

Answer (score 1):

All non-`null` strings contain the empty string `""`.

In your code, the `if` at the moment it is executed, is, actually:

```
if ("hai".contains(""))
```

The expression inside the  `if` yields `true`, satisfying it.

About the output, once again, it is like:

```
System.out.println("its working" + "".length());
```

Thus printing `its working0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if path contains the empty string, but every string (even the empty string) matches this condition so the test always passes.

Comment: The title of the post says otherwise

Comment: Dici could you please for the above example which i modified

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct.  The empty string "" is a substring of any String.  Just like the empty set is a subset of any set.

If you evaluate `"name".substring(0,0)` you get `""`.  Therefore, "" is a substring of "name".

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` method uses `indexOf` method internally. If you will look deeper in the source code then you will find a fragment like

```
if (targetCount == 0) {
    return fromIndex;
}
```

where `targetCount` is the length of the target string (empty string in your case) and as you can see that if the length of the **target string is 0** then the method returns fromIndex, which has the value 0. The `contains` return true because `0 > -1`, the body of contains method looks like this

```
indexOf(s.toString()) > -1
```